# Why is my $.ajax not showing up in Network tab, but opening in a new tab works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqxhr

Here is my AJAX code:

```
jQuery.ajax({url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    data: getParams,
    /*success: function (json, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if(jQuery.active <= 1){
            waitDialog.removeWaitDialog();
        }

        createProcessButtonEvent();

        ajaxError = false;
        returnFunction(jqXHR.responseJSON);
    },*/
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if(jQuery.active <= 1){
            waitDialog.removeWaitDialog();
        }

        createProcessButtonEvent();

        var response;
        if (typeof jqXHR.responseJSON === 'object') {
            response = jqXHR.responseJSON;
        } else {
            response = jqXHR.responseText;
        }

        if(response.errors.length == 1){ // jsonResults.message != ''
            if(!warningMessage){ //hard coded for ad designer
                jQuery('#alertMessageText').text(response.errors[0].message);
                jQuery('#alertMessage').show();
                jQuery('#waitDialog').jqmHide();
                ajaxError = true;
                return;
            }
            warningMessage.displayMessage(response.errors[0].message);
            jQuery('.popup').modal('hide');
            jQuery('.popup').not('.persist').remove();
        }
        if (response.errors.length > 1){
            for(var n = 0; n < response.errors.length; n++){
                if (response.errors[n].id == 1){ // 2005
                    window.location.href = '/login?destination=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
                }
                if (response.errors[n].id == 9500){
                    statusMessage.displayMessage(response.errors[n].message);
                }
            }
            ajaxError = true;
            //if(errorFunction){
            //  errorFunction(jsonResults);
            //}
            waitDialog.removeWaitDialog();
        }

        if (!ajaxError) {
            returnFunction(jqXHR.responseJSON);
        }
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

I tell it to go to `http://127.0.0.1/api/parameter`, where the `parameter` is an invalid resource. My API returns in a new tab:

`{"errors":[{"id":3,"message":"GET route not defined for /api/parameter"}],data:{}}`

I have it returning with a 500 status code because accessing an invalid resource is an error. When I call the actual AJAX, I get `jqXHR.responseJSON` is `null`, and `jqXHR.responseText` is `''`.

I have tried using both `success:` and `error:` blocks, and tried the `complete:` because it seemed like my API was resolving the call after the error block had been called, as you can see with the comments.

So I get `TypeError: response is null`, because my response object is never populated, and the strangest thing is that my call to `parameter?parameters=here` is never available to inspect in the Network

Comment: perhaps you've filtered out XHR's from the network tab - which browser are you using - though, reading the rest of your question suggests the title of the question is very misleading.

Comment: is `url` same origin or cross origin

Comment: @JaromandaX, you read my mind! I disabled the XHR filtering in my browser, sorted by status code, and looked for my call. Only 200s and 304s, no 500. `url` is a relative URL that always points to my localhost. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I changed the status code to 501 instead of wondering why status code 500 wouldn't work. Got to know when to fold them instead of always wanting to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have control over the API, I changed this specific error to return with status code 501 Not Implemented, instead of 500, and it seems to work. It looks like this was a very unique edge case.